# Listbox with more than one Control

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Can somebody help me out in creating a listbox with a checkbox and star rating control align horizontally? I want it for WP7 using C# and XAML.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to code a custom list here is an example:

You need to include ControlToolkit:

```
xmlns:ControlsToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls"
```

and here is code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" SelectionMode="Multiple" 
    ItemContainerStyle="StaticResource  ListBoxCheckedStyle}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <CheckBox Checked="{Binding YourPropertyPath}"/>               
                 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Width="150" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                  <ControlsToolkit:Rating Height="50" Grid.Row="0" x:Name="rating" ItemCount="5">
            <ControlsToolkit:Rating.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ControlsToolkit:Rating.ItemsPanel>
        </ControlsToolkit:Rating>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

You can download sample from here:
[DownloadSample](https://github.com/matthieugd/WP7Samples/tree/master/RatingControlSample)

or check details here:
[Sample site](http://wp7wonders.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/use-the-rating-control-in-windows-phone-7/)

You can get more detail on these: 
[CustomDataTemplateSelector](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-Windows-Phone-7-DataTemplateSelector-and-CustomDataTemplateSelector)
[WP7 Checked ListBox in different ways](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Implementing-a-WP7-Checked-ListBox-in-different-ways).

Comment: In the code you have given, I want a StarControl instead of the Image but its not coming.

Comment: The StarControl is not visible. The checkbox and text is coming properly.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox Checked="{Binding YourPropertyPath}"/>
        <ns:StarControl/>
      </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: <ns:StarControl/>
This is showing error by saying that StarControl is not supported in Silverlight Project.

Comment: Correct - this is not a standard control. You will need to source a control for this part of your UI.

Comment: @ColinE by "source a control", Do you mean like custom control?

Comment: @Alaa.Ali yes, just Google and you will find controls that are suitable http://wp7wonders.wordpress.com/2010/10/15/use-the-rating-control-in-windows-phone-7/