# is there rating control, windows phone 7

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

Is there a rating control in windows phone? something like the controls existing in silver-light toolkit, i know there isn't one in the silverlight   or i have to customize a control myself?
I am using windows phone 7.1, C#, Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not inside the silverlight toolkit, you have to customize the control, Please Check the following question, same as your idea and have what you need [Listbox with more than one Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169053/listbox-with-more-than-one-controls-in-wp7-using-c-sharp/10169070#comment13048906_10169070)

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight Toolkit for WP7 currently does not have RatingControl . You could check the third party controls like Telerik etc. which provides the RatingControl .

Below is an article that can help you get started with the Telerik RadRatingControl.

[Telerik RadRatingControl in Windows Phone](http://windowsphonerocks.com/telerik-radcontrols-for-windows-phone-article-5-radrating-rating-control/)